# We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available Windows Error

Tags: ethernet, domain, credentials

This has been happening for a while at our site. We have deployed about 3 dozen laptops across the organization and have attached them to a med cart (like a toolbox on wheels). This laptop is connected to a UPS which in turn is plugged in to the wall. The med cart is in a locked room, only to be used to print patient charts when there is a medical emergency.

What we have noticed is, if no one uses the laptop for over a month, when any user attempt to log on, they sometimes get the error "**we can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available.**" Laptops are all running Windows 10 22H2 and they are in the AD domain, but we use wireless.

I have researched this error and there's a series of recommendations, none of which work or are too cumbersome.

The quick fix our techs use, is to bring the med cart out of their closet and move it close to a network drop and use connect the laptop using an ethernet cable, then log on using their local (or AD) account.

This works and is relatively quick but, in an emergency, this walk-around is not going to work.

Has anyone seen happen and has found a way to fix it with little or no user intervention?

Comment: Unfortunately the only real solution is to routinely log into the network using the domain

Comment: Based on  @Ramhound statement, add a weekly item to whatever calendar app you use to log in and then off. This also would confirm the laptop is working, and provide a time to *perform required updates*. As a side note, AFAIK Windows 10 is *not* certified for critical medical applications, though that may not be the cause of the network issue.